# Google's new restriction on IBM MobileFirst application center

Tags: android, google-play-services, provisioning-profile, android-security, mobilefirst-appcenter

IBM Application Center has been removed from Google play due to violating their Malicious Behavior policy as the application contains security vulnerabilities.

the application in question is basically a repository of mobile applications configured by our end, this application is meant to host some other applications specified for a specific organization.

the application was up and running for three years now, but apparently, Google has changed its policy in this regard.

my question: is there any way that would help me republish the application to the Google play without changing its meaning?

Below is the email we received from Google:

> Hello Google Play Developer, After review, Application Name, xxxxxxx, has been removed from Google Play because it uses software
>   that contains security vulnerabilities and violates our [Malicious
>   Behavior policy.](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/) Your app will not be available to users until you
>   submit a compliant update.
>
> Here's how you can submit your app for another review:
>
> 1. Fix all of the security vulnerabilities listed in your Play Console that have past deadlines.
> 2. Remember your app must comply with all policies listed in the Developer Program Policies and additional enforcement could occur if
>      there are further policy issues with your apps.
> 3. Sign in to your Play Console and submit your policy-compliant app. If you have technical questions about a vulnerability, you can post to
>      Stack Overflow and use the tag “android-security.” For clarification
>      on steps you need to take to resolve this issue, you can contact our
>      developer support team.

Comment: You meant it's a copy right issue?

Comment: no, it's not, it's a privacy policy issue because the application hosts other applications, so it somehow acts as Google Play itself, it was functioning properly for the three previous years though, it was removed just today.

Comment: Might be that other applications have changed their security policy for usage

Comment: Why do you upload IBM Application Center into Google Playstore? Application Center is an in-house enterprise store.

Comment: @VivinK it's the customer's requirements to upload it to Google Play, it was functioning without any problem, but when Google changed their policy, we're wondering if there's any workaround that we could do to republish it again to the store.